The action of $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{k}/k)$ on $\pi_1^{\mathrm{ét}}(\mathbb{G}_m)$
$\newcommand{\et}{\mathrm{ét}}$Let $k$ be a number field. Let $\mathbb{G}_m=\operatorname{Spec}(k[t^{\pm1}])$. The homotopy exact sequence for the étale fundamental group is given by
$$1\longrightarrow \pi_1^{\et}(\mathbb{G}_{m,\overline{k}})\longrightarrow \pi_1^{\et}(\mathbb{G}_m)\longrightarrow \operatorname{Gal}(\overline{k}/k)\longrightarrow 1 $$
We have $\pi_1^{\et}(\mathbb{G}_{m,\overline{k}})\cong\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ because a cofinal system of Galois covers is $\{f_n:x\mapsto x^n\}$ and we have all roots of unity over $\overline{k}$ so we get $\operatorname{Aut}(f_n)=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. $\mathbb{G}_m(k)\neq0$ so the exact sequence splits and we have an isomorphism $$\pi_1^{\et}(\mathbb{G}_m)\cong \widehat{\mathbb{Z}}\rtimes \operatorname{Gal}(\overline{k}/k)$$
I'm struggling to understand what the action of $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{k}/k)$ on $\pi_1^{\et}(\mathbb{G}_{m,\overline{k}})=\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ looks like. The thing that's confusing me is that I think the action of the geometric fundamental group is permuting roots of unity and the action of the absolute Galois group would do the same thing. I know there's something basic that will unlock all of this for me but I'm not seeing it!

The geometric fundamental group is not permuting roots of unity, it is multiplying with them: think about the étale cover $\mathbb{G}_{m, \overline{k}}\to\mathbb{G}_{m, \overline{k}}$, $x\mapsto x^n$. Its automorphisms are given by the maps $x\mapsto \zeta x$ where $\zeta$ ranges over $n$-th roots of unity. The action of the absolute Galois group of $k$ now does indeed permute them. This exhibits $\pi_1(\mathbb{G}_m)$ as the limit of the semidirect products $\mathbb{Z}/n\rtimes \operatorname{Gal}(\overline{k}/k)$, which is $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}\rtimes \operatorname{Gal}(\overline{k}/k) $ where the action is through the cyclotomic character.
